# Tilemap vs terrain vs optimized mesh for top-down game

Tags: unity, performance, optimization, terrain, 3d-meshes

I'm experimenting with a top down vertical scroller in Unity, with a perspective camera, NOT orthogonal.
(It's unclear how 'pixelated'/pixel art I will want the graphics but that's another question)

The map would be longer/taller than it is wide, and consist of squares, the image of which is different for each square. I'd like to be able to have 3 levels of height in the map. Most of the map would be flat square surfaces at those heights, but with occasional slopes between them. Some or all of the flat surfaces would be animated, eg water, and there would be buildings etc. scattered around.
The map will eventually be procedural but for now I can hand-make it.

This sort of thing, but with more levels and possibly a different graphical style (hence 'experimenting'):[image]

I'm considering the best way to do this. Seems like three options:

1. three tilemaps, one for each level. Create additional 3D objects, or a some optimized mesh objects, for the slopes. Note: if this is efficient then I would probably use other tilemaps for eg trees, buildings and other decor on the levels, so possibly double the number of tilemaps
2. a 3D terrain. Separate objects for the buildings and trees.
3. An optimized mesh for the terrain. Separate objects for the buildings and trees.

Note 1: I don't mind having fairly large tiles for the ground, to reduce mesh complexity etc.

What do I mean by 'best'? Clearly some of those are harder or more complicated than others, and the relative simplicity of eg (2) or (3) seems nice (and I suspect that it would have other benefits, graphical and otherwise). But speed would be a consideration, probably the main or only consideration in the end.

Note 2 : making this for mobile is not a high priority, but it would be nice to get it so it works for that too without a complete rebuild. I hear that might leave out option (2)

What's my best choice? Or is there a better method I haven't considered?
With whatever you suggest, is there anything else I should look in to (eg instancing instead of separate models, etc.)?